# How can i get the list of databases in Postgresql in python

Tags: python, linux, postgresql

I want to get the list of all databases in `Postgresql` server in python list.
Basically then i want to create those insode another database
But i am not able to get it.

This is what i have tried

```
config_read = {
          'host':'psql-002',
          'database':'tesdb',
          'user':'pguser',
          'port':'5432',
          'password':'mypass'
          }


class ExportPSQL():

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect(**config_read) 
            self.conn = conn
        except:
            print "Eror Connecting database"  

    def run(self):
    # Get a list of databases with :
        db_command=" psql -h localhost -U pguser tesdb -c '\l'"
        db_list = os.popen(db_command)
```

Comment: Take a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1304 .

Comment: Which is the other database? Postgresql?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto yes other databse is also postgres

Comment: So why don't you do it all in Postgresql in instead of using Python?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto how can i do it in postgres. i thought i had to manually export and import  each database and i had 30 databases. so i thought i will automate it with python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it all with [`pg_dumpall`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-dumpall.html) and [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) as superuser

```
pg_dumpall -h localhost -U postgres -f pg_dumpall.sql
```

If you want to copy only the schema then use the `--schema-only` parameter.

To restore it to another cluster

```
psql -f pg_dumpall.sql postgres
```

Answer (score 2):

What's missing in your solution is the reading and parsing of the information you get from `psql`:

```
def get_database_info(host, user):
    records, _ = subprocess.Popen(['psql','-lA','-F\x02','-R\x01','-h',host,'-U',user ],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    records = records.split('\x01')
    header = records[1].split('\x02')
    return [dict(zip(header,line.split('\x02'))) for line in records[2:-1]]
```