# Display all databases names from a given ip, port, username and password using python

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I need to show all found databases name.

I have found solutions that obtain information from a known database but in my case I do not know the 'database_name.db'.

someone can help me please!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i get the list of databases in Postgresql in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348772/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-databases-in-postgresql-in-python)

Comment: @eshirvana That could be an answer but I don't have the field `database`, that field is the one that I do not know and I want to obtain. thxs

Answer (score 0):

well, you don't have to :

```
psql -h localhost -U pguser -c '\l'
```

this way you will connect to default database (called postgres).
postgres connections need to connect to a database.
output:

```
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 mytestdb  | postgres | UTF8     | en_CA.UTF-8 | en_CA.UTF-8 | 
 imdb      | postgres | UTF8     | en_CA.UTF-8 | en_CA.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_CA.UTF-8 | en_CA.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_CA.UTF-8 | en_CA.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_CA.UTF-8 | en_CA.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```